# How can I handle routing with express when I use a static site?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http

When the user goes to mydomain.com/game, I want the user to see what is displayed in my public folder. This works completely fine when I do this:

```
app.use('/game', express.static('public'))
```

The problem is that I want to extract some information from the URL, but as I do not know how to continue the routing when using a static site, I can't extract any information. For example, if the user inputs mydomain.com/game/123, I want to retrieve 123, but still route the person to my public folder, like mydomain.com/game does.

Any ideas on how to handle this problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has worked for me in a similar situation

```
app.use('/game/:id', (req, res) => {
  // do something with id
  res.redirect(302, '/game');
}
```

Comment: This works great! For some reason there is a time restriction on marking a correct answer though. I will do it when the time is up.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use two middlewares: first is your static middleware, the secont is the fallback, with id (123)

```
app.use('/game', express.static('public'));
app.use('/game/:id', function(req, res) { // when static not found, it passed to this middleware, this process it
    console.log('your id', req.params.id);
    res.send('ok');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react static files and you want to serve all react routes using express then you have to do thing like below-

1.First of all you have to run command in your react folder

```
npm run build
```

this will create your build folder in react app having one index.html file which you have to serve through express.
Now come to your server.js file and write there

```
const express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/client/build/index.html'));
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```